# Verification for code to check if a number is a palindrome

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
#include <iostream>
 #include "conio.h"
 #include <math.h>

 using namespace std;

void main()
{
    int n;
    int sum=0;
    int a[16];
    cin>>n;
    int i=0;
    while(n>0)
    {

        a[i]=n%10;
        n=n/10;
        i++;
    }
    for(int j=0;j<=i;j++)
    {
        if(a[j]!=a[i-j])
        {
            sum=1;
        }
    }
    if(sum==1)
        cout<<"not a palindrome";
    else
        cout<<" palindrome";
    _getch();
}
```

I typed the above code to check whether a number is a palindrome but I keep getting that it's not a palindrome irrespective of the number I enter. Where have I gone wrong ?

Comment: Store the input text in a `std::string` and check whether that's a palindrome. Much simpler than converting text to an integer and then extracting digits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the end of the `while` cycle `i` will store the number of elements in `a`. So in the cycle above you should compare `a[0]` (the first element) to `a[i-1]` (the last element). Instead you compare `a[0]` to `a[i]` which is not a digit of the number. Think of how you can fix that.

Comment: Also worth noting that you don't need to check all the numbers twice.

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth I am here to help for the specific problem. I have not provided a full solution but only a tip, trying to stimulate the OP to think of how to solve his/her problem alone.

Comment: Thanks I got it now :)

Answer (score 1):

You simply have an off by one error:
Change this

```
if(a[j]!=a[i-j]){
```

to

```
if(a[j]!=a[i-j-1]){
```

For example, conside 11.
Then i is 2, so i-j is 2-0 i.e. 2, when j is 0, which means you compare a[0] with a[2], not a[1].

Comment: Yes thanks. And also I have to change j<=i to j<i :)